# FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for- MobileFirst Maximo Anywhere 7.6

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

Environment Details
Websphere :8.5.5.3
Maximo:7.6
Maximo Anywhere 7.6

***** I am not using eclipse 
** I ceheked almost all suggestions on Stack overflow and most of them not working with me since i am using WebSphere.

```
I Have this issue when i am trying to run build all-deploy on Maximo anywhere 


 FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'worklightconsole'. Possibly
the MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project 'worklightconsol
e' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBean
s. If it is not running, full error details are available in the Worklight Devel
opment Server Eclipse Console view.
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getResponse(RESTClient.
java:1189)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTResponse(RESTCli
ent.java:1326)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTFileResponse(RES
TClient.java:1348)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.commands.DeployAdapter.getResponse(DeployAdap
ter.java:41)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.ActionClient.execute(ActionClient.
java:85)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.AbstractActionElement.executeComman
d(AbstractActionElement.java:76)
```

Comment: Something is misconfigured in your server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Maximo Anywhere While installing they fill the worklight.server.context value in build.pro with mobile-first operation console context root value  and this is causing this error. I have to change it to mobile-first project context root value.

Comment: We ask at MaximoAnywhere install time for this Project runtime URL in our panels, but you can certainly change it directly in our build.properties after our installation.

This is the property where our particular Mobilefirst project is deployed.
worklight.server.context=MaximoAnywhere

This is the property of the MobileFirst admin context.
worklight.admin.server.context=wladmin

Comment: yes, this is what i did but maximo Configuration tool they set it wrongly